# HTTPHandler does not handle secondary requests

Tags: c#, http, iis, httphandler

I want to run my personal web sites via an httphandler (I have a web server and static ip at home.)
Eventually, I will incorporate a data access layer and domain router into the handler, but for now, I am just trying to use it to return static web content.

I have the handler mapped to all verbs and paths with no access restrictions in IIS 7 on Windows 7.

I have added a little file logging at the beginning of process request.  As it is the first thing in the handler, I use the logging to tell me when the handler is hit.

At the moment, the handler just returns a single web page that I have already written.
The handler itself is mostly just this:

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "index.htm",
            FileMode.Open))
        {
            fs.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
        }
```

I understand that this won't work for anything but the one file.

So my issue is this: the HTML file has links to some images in it.  I would expect that the browser would come back to the server to get those images as new requests.  I would expect those requests to fail (because they'd be mapped to index.htm).  But I would expect to see the logging hit at least twice (and potentially hit recursively).  However, I only see a single request.  The web page comes up and the images are 'X's.

When I refresh the browser, I see another request come through, but only for the root page again.  The page is basic HTML, I do not have an asp.net application (nor do I want one, I like HTML/CSS/JS).

What do I have to do to get more than just the first request sent from the browser?  I assume I'm just totally off the mark because I wrote an HTTP Module first, but strangely got the same exact behavior.  I'm thinking I need to specify some response headers, but don't see that in any example.

Comment: It sounds like the browser is not requesting the images.  Use a tool like fiddler or firebug to see what the browser is doing.